# Unset a row in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, unset

I have this array $output which looks like this:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [0] => 1a
        [1] => 1b
        [2] => 1c
    )
    [1] => Array(
        [0] => 2a
        [1] => 2b
        [2] => 2c
    )
    [2] => Array(
        [0] => 3a
        [1] => 3b
        [2] => 3c
    )
    [3] => Array(
        [0] => 4a
        [1] => 4b
        [2] => 4c
    )
)
```

and so on...

When I want to remove the second element I just use:

```
$output = unset($output[1]);
```

to get the following:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [0] => 1a
        [1] => 1b
        [2] => 1c
    )
    [1] => Array(
        [0] => 3a
        [1] => 3b
        [2] => 3c
    )
    [2] => Array(
        [0] => 4a
        [1] => 4b
        [2] => 4c
    )
)
```

My question is how to remove every second element of every element in the array ([0][1], [1][1], [2][1], [3][1] ,...) to get the following:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [0] => 1a
        [1] => 1c
    )
    [1] => Array(
        [0] => 2a
        [1] => 2c
    )
    [2] => Array(
        [0] => 3a
        [1] => 3c
    )
    [3] => Array(
        [0] => 4a
        [1] => 4c
    )
)
```

Comment: [unset()](http://es.php.net/unset) doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 25):

Can't be done with a simple command, but you can use a loop:

```
foreach(array_keys($output) as $key) {
   unset($output[$key][1]);
}
```

Comment: Very helpful, thanks!  To add to your answer, if you want to keep your remaining keys sequential after the unset, you can include at the end of (and within) your `foreach`: `$output[$key] = array_values($output[$key]);`.  The `array_values()` will rebase the keys so they are sequential starting from zero.

Comment: If you want to reindex after unsetting, just call `array_splice()` as @cwallen demonstrates.

Answer (score 10):

Clean and neat:

```
$f = function(&$a,$k) { unset($a[1]); };
array_walk($arr, $f);
```

Or:

```
array_walk($arr, function (&$a, $k) {
  unset($a[1]); 
});
```

Comment: Why declare `$k`?  You never use it.

Answer (score 8):

You can iterate over the array, and `unset()` what you want in each sub-array:

```
foreach($output as &$item) {
    unset($item[2]);
}
unset($item); // unset reference
```

Comment: Make sure you include the `&` like arnaud has above, this is required to reference it when you call unset

Answer (score 2):

You'd use a combination of `array_map` and `array_splice`:

```
function removeSecond( array &$arr )
{
    array_splice( $arr, 1, 1 );
}
$out = array_map( 'removeSecond', $input );
```

The problem with `unset` is that it will leave the indexes as they were:

```
$ php -r '$arr = array(array(0,1,2)); unset($arr[0][1]); var_dump($arr);'
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(0)
    [2]=>
    int(2)
  }
}
```

While splice will update the indexes:

```
$ php -r '$arr = array(array(0,1,2)); array_splice($arr[0], 1, 1); var_dump($arr);'
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(0)
    [1]=>
    int(2)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($array as $key=>$val){ unset($val[1]); }
```

Comment: This code-only answer does not affect the original `$array`, but an element within a copy of `$array`.  Within `$val`, the  `1`-keyed element will be removed, but `$array` is never mutated.  Proof: https://3v4l.org/aZ52f

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
public function array_unset_key_in_children($array, $keyToUnsetInChildren)
{ 
    $newArray = [];
    foreach($array as $key=>$subArray) { 
        unset($subArray[$keyToUnsetInChild]);
        $newArray[$key] = $subArray;
    }
    return $newArray;
}
```

Comment: @mickmackusa thanks, I've removed "array_key_exists" before unset, but about mutation -  I had a case (couldnt explain why but it was hundred percent case) that mutating original array ended up using several times  more memory (causing "memory exhausted, trying to allocate..." ) while creating new arrays did go incomparably easier.  Had been debugging that case for a day, and this ended for sure to me.

Comment: Okay.  You might like to explain the benefit of your snippet in your answer.