# Unset index of an array inside another array

Tags: php, json

I have an array with in which there is another array. I need to unset a index of the sub array.

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'country_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'description' => string 'test' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array
      'country_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'description' => string 'sel' (length=5)
  2 => 
    array
      'country_id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'description' => string 'soul' (length=5)
```

Now i need to unset `country_id` of all the three index of the master array. I am using PHP and I initially thought unset will do until i realized my array is nested.

How can I do this?

Comment: `foreach($array as &$element){unset($element['country_id'];}`

Comment: `foreach ($array as &$sub) unset($sub['country_id']);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - unset in a multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260468/php-unset-in-a-multidimensional-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($original_array as &$element) {
  unset($element['country_id']);
}
```

why `&$element`?

Because `foreach (...)` will perform a copy, so we need to pass the reference to the "current" element in order to unset it (and not his copy)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($masterArray as &$subArray)
    unset($subArray['country_id']);
```

The idea is that you take each sub array by reference and unset the key within that.

---

EDIT: another idea, just to make things interesting, would be to use the `array_walk` function.

```
array_walk($masterArray, function (&$item) { unset ($item['country_id']); });
```

I'm not sure that it's any more readable, and the function call will make it slower. Still, the option is there.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($yourArray as &$arr)
{
   unset($arr['country_id']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
foreach ($array as &$item) {
  unset($item['country_id']);
}
```

but after loop you should really unset reference otherwise you might get into trouble so the correct code is:

```
foreach ($array as &$item) {
  unset($item['country_id']);
}
unset($item);
```