# PHP - Get array within array and store/manipulate

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an existing array in PHP like so (when i use `print_r`):

```
Array (
    [0] => Array(
        [value] => 188
        [label] => Lucy
    )  
    [1] => Array (
        [value] => 189
        [label] => Jessica
    ) 
    [2] => Array (
        [value] => 192
        [label] => Lisa
    ) 
    [3] => Array (
        [value] => 167
        [label] => Carol
    ) 
    // and so on...
)
```

From this array i need to manipulate or create a new array like so:

```
Array (
    [Lucy] => 188
    [Jessica] => 189
    [Lisa] => 192
    [Carol] => 167
)
```

What's the best way of doing so?

I need the names to become the keys so i can then sort alphabetically like so:

```
uksort($array, 'strnatcasecmp');
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt? Should be pretty simple.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - unset in a multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260468/php-unset-in-a-multidimensional-array)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMHO the best and easiest option is this:

```
$newArray = [];
foreach ($array as $var) {
   $newArray[$var['label']] = $var['value'];
}
```

Note: if doesn't work because of `[]` then change first line to classic version: `$newArray = array();` as it's the same.

Answer (score 6):

PHP 5.5 has a nice new [array_column()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function that will do exactly that for you. I think you want something like this:

```
$result = array_column($array, 'value', 'label');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use array_reduce as well, like so:

```
$new_array = array_reduce($old_array, function($new_array, $item) {
    $new_array[$item['label']] = $item['value'];
    return $new_array;
}, array());
```

In simple scenarios this is arguably overkill. In applications where a lot of array transformation is going on, the second argument of *array_reduce* can be factored out and replaced depending on context.