# PHP multidimensional array remove elements by key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional Array which looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Edeka Blaschek
        [description] => Lebensmittelmarkt mit Frischfleischtheke und BÃ¤ckerei BÃ¼sch
        [latitude] => 51.1178
        [longitude] => 6.77537
        [distance] => 0.18105522823916723
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => Autohaus Kopenhagen
        [description] => Peugeot HÃ¤ndler
        [latitude] => 51.1161
        [longitude] => 6.77481
        [distance] => 0.33650698548914737
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 10
        [name] => Hallenbad Nievenheim
        [description] => Schwimmbad mit Sauna und SonnenbÃ¤nken, sowie kleinem AuÃŸenbereich
        [latitude] => 51.1211
        [longitude] => 6.77857
        [distance] => 0.38752806088549746
    )
)
```

now I want to remove the distance key and value completely from all arrays in the array. It should look like this:

```
    Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Edeka Blaschek
        [description] => Lebensmittelmarkt mit Frischfleischtheke und BÃ¤ckerei BÃ¼sch
        [latitude] => 51.1178
        [longitude] => 6.77537
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => Autohaus Kopenhagen
        [description] => Peugeot HÃ¤ndler
        [latitude] => 51.1161
        [longitude] => 6.77481
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 10
        [name] => Hallenbad Nievenheim
        [description] => Schwimmbad mit Sauna und SonnenbÃ¤nken, sowie kleinem AuÃŸenbereich
        [latitude] => 51.1211
        [longitude] => 6.77857
    )
)
```

I've tried the solutions mentioned here: [PHP - unset in a multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260468/php-unset-in-a-multidimensional-array)
but they didn't worked for me, what I'm doing wrong here? Could be very simple sorry but I'm new in PHP.

EDIT: This is the code I tried:

```
foreach(array_keys($tempArray) as $key) {
   unset($tempArray[$key][5]);
}
```

And this:

```
foreach($tempArray as $key=>$val){
   unset($val[5]); 
}
```

$tempArray is the array that I want to change.

Comment: please show us the code you tried

Comment: I saw this already but the solutions didn't worked for me or I did something wrong..

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: In your first snippet, you don't have a subarray with the key of `5`, so that cannot work.  In the second, you are not modifying `$tempArray`, but the element within a copy of the temp array which has the key `5` (which even if you had `5`-keyed element, you would not be affecting the original `$tempArray`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
array_map(function($v){array_pop($v); return $v;}, $array);
```

**Note**, array_pop pop the last element of array. if the distance is not the last key, you can use unset() instead

Comment: Didn't worked for me, nothing has changed, the distance is already there :/

Comment: Sorry, doesn't put the result in a new variable, now it works for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
   foreach ($mainArray as $key => $mainData){
    foreach ($subArray as $subData){ 
       if($mainData['distance'] == $subData['distance']){
        unset($mainArray[$key]); break; 
  }
   } 
     }
```

Try this way. –

Answer (score -1):

Use array_values() function in php.I suppose it will works.

Comment: I looked here http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-values.php but it seems to me that this function only shows the values of an array and doesn't filter, can you give an example please?

Comment: foreach ($mainArray as $key => $mainData){
        foreach ($subArray as $subData){
            if($mainData['distance'] == $subData['distance']){
                unset($mainArray[$key]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }Try this way.